# C - split string using multiple delimiters in C

Tags: c, string, split

How to write a function that split a string using multiples delimiters, which could be char like ',' and could be string like "or".

For example, for the string `char * string = "a or b or c, 8"`, I would like to print :

```
a 
b
c
8
```

Comment: would it also split words like "mirror" into `mirr" and (nothing) ?  "mirror razor error" => "mirr raz err" ?  If it's simple like that you could just use a loop that copies characters to an output, skipping over / past any of the patterns that it sees.

Comment: With the commands [strlen](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strlen), [strncmp](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strncmp) and [strcspn](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strcspn) (see also [strpbrk](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk)) it would be possible to write such a function. The idea is to search the source string for the first character of the delimiters, if found, test all delimiters from that position in the source string, if found, break the string at that point, increase the position by the delimiter length and continue.

Comment: Another question to ask: do you need to _store_ all of the substrings, or just print them sequentially?

Answer (score 3):

I suggest that you first use [`strtok`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strtok) with the delimiter string `" ,"` and then filter out tokens which have a special meaning, such as `"or"`.

Here is an example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

int main( void )
{
    char string[] = "a or b or c, 8";
    const char *delim = " ,"; 
    char *token;

    token = strtok( string, delim );

    while ( token != NULL )
    {
        if ( strcmp( token, "or" ) != 0 )
        {
            printf( "%s\n", token );
        }

        token = strtok( NULL, delim );
    }
}
```

This program has the following output:

```
a
b
c
8
```

Note that `strtok` requires that the string is writable, because it writes null characters into the string. Therefore, you cannot use a string literal such as

```
char *string = "a or b or c, 8";
```

That is why I am using a writable array instead:

```
char string[] = "a or b or c, 8";
```

If you want your code to also work on string literals, then you cannot use `strtok`, but will have to use other functions instead, such as [`strpbrk`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/strpbrk).

Answer (score -1):

```
void printsubstr(const char *start, const char *end, int printEmpty)
{
    if(printEmpty || start < end)
    {
        printf("\"");
        while(start < end && *start) printf("%c", *start++);
        printf("\"\n");
    }
}

void print(const char *str, const char *delim, int printEmpty)
{
    const char *found;
    size_t delimlen = strlen(delim);

    while((found = strstr(str, delim)))
    {
        printsubstr(str, found, printEmpty);
        str = found + delimlen;
    }
    printsubstr(str, str + strlen(str), printEmpty);
}

int main(void)
{
    print( "ormirror razor error", "or", 1);
    printf("-----------------------\n");
    print( "ormirror razor error", "or", 0);
}
```

Comment: For the input stated in the question, this will print `, 8` as one result, but OP only wants the `8` to be printed. (I am not the one who downvoted.)

Answer (score -3):

You can use a simple function like this to split a string by multiple delimiters:

```
void split_and_or(char *str) {
    const char *delim = "and or";
    char *token;
    token = strtok(str, delim);
    while (token != NULL) {
        printf("%s\n", token);
        token = strtok(NULL, delim);
    }}
```

and in main:

```
int main() {
    char str[] = "a or b and c or d";
    split_and_or(str);
    return 0;                                                                       
}
```

However this code only works for Strings that do not contains charachters from the previous delimiters, so you can not use 'o' as one because the delimiter "or" contains 'o'.

Comment: With the OP asking this type of question, understanding of C is likely at a fairly low level. This answer would benefit from elaboration on what's happening and _how_.

Comment: For the input stated in the question, your code will print `b\nc,\n8`, but OP wants it to print `a\nb\nc\n8`.

Comment: I literally said that you can't use this method when the delimiter contains a character of the characters we want to split.